# Python Djando easiest way to display url parameters

Tags: django

What's the easiest way to display url parameters in a html webpage
For example, url = example.com/item/ABC1234.
Want to display a simple string "this page is for ABC1234"

Comment: You should show your code, in this case your view, and url config.

Answer (score 1):

You can send that value in your `context` to the view.

Given an url like this:

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^item/(?P<item_code>[0-9A-Z]+)', item_view, name="url_name")
...
```

And a view like this:

**views.py**

```
def item_view(request, item_code):
    ...  # Do something here
    context = {'item_code': item_code, }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)
```

And then in your template you can use:

**your_template.html**

```
<p>this page is for {{ item_code }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the *easiest* way is to just use GET variables:

URL: `http://example.com/item?code=ABC1234`

```
def item(request):
    return HttpResponse("this is page for %s" % request.GET.get('code', 'default')
```

It's quite flexible since you can add and use more variables without modifying your url pattern.

However this is not the *prettiest* method.